# how to deploy servlet in Web browser?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I have create My First "Hello World" Servlet in Eclipse.
It is running properly in Eclipse Browser.
I'm using Apache Tomcat, and it is also running properly.

How can I deploy my Servlet in Web browser like Internet Explorer, Chrome, Mozilla Firefox etc? I don't want to deploy my servlet in Eclipse browser.

Comment: Do not ask the same question over and over. If you can't seem to find your previously asked questions back, click at the link behind your username which appears in the gray top bar. It brings you to your user profile wherein you can find all previously asked questions. If you'd like to update your question, use the "edit" link below the question which you can see when you're logged in.

Answer (score 4):

You don't deploy to a browser. You deploy to a server. Just deploy to server and start the server the usual way (as you did in Eclipse). Then, just enter the servlet's URL in the address bar of the webbrowser of your choice yourself. It can be exactly the same URL as you see in Eclipse browser's address bar. If necessary, bookmark this URL in your favourite webbrowser so that you don't need to copypaste/enter it yourself everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Window** menu in eclipse then click on "web browser" then click on "Internet explorer".That't it.....

Comment: I am sure this is the answer the OP was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, servlets are not deployed in Browsers, they are deployed on server and accessed through browsers.

Secondly: what you can do is, just copy paste the URL from eclipse browser to mozilla or chrome to access your servlet. All that you have to make sure is that the tomcat server configured in your eclipse and on which application containing this servlet is deployed, is up and running.

If you want to access this without eclipse tomcat, goto the local tomcat installation, you should have a deploy folder there, create a war file of your webapplication and copy it to the deploy folder and start te tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

You deploy application in WebServer (Tomcat in your case) not in browsers.

In eclipse, add your application in tomcat server (in servers view), start the server and open a browser of your choice.

Then put in url `http://localhost:8080/NameOfYourServlet`

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the url from eclipse browser and paste on url bar of which browser you need. There is no separate deploy for each browser. Another thing you can change your eclipse default browser.If you changed,  project will start in browser you selected instead of eclipse browser.